# Design module of emulator missing on my screen. What's wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 2.3 and I just don't see no emulator in the design view. When I try to drag and drop any widget like textview, it doesn't works and not appears. (I have pasted a link to the image below:)

I tried pasting a code for textview but that too, the textview isn't visible and I just see a plus sign on the top right.

Look at screenshot below:
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there. With a `zoom in level 1000%` you can only see that screen. **Zoom out** please. Then pick a device, and API level. it seems it's `null`.

Comment: I zoomed out, but I still don't see anything else than the plus sign.

Comment: Please elaborate, how do I pick the device and API level?

Comment: Look at your screenshot, there are 3 icons on top of your "question mark", if you look at the right side of android icon you can see it's null, click that and select the desired API level.